# uniqueEntity multiple fields

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I have two unique attributes in my entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true, nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, unique=true)
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;
```

I have add the uniqueentity annotation at the first of the class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = {"username"}, message="This user already exits")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = {"email"}, message="This email already exists")
 */
class User
```

But the email field is good tested and detect if I have already the same email in database, but the username not.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Best regards

EDIT:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'form.label.email', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.placeholder.email')))
                ->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'form.label.username', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.placeholder.username')))
...

->add('envoyer', 'submit', array('label' => 'form.submit', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-lg-12 col-xs-12 btn btn-primary submit')))
            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique email and unique username "independently"

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="This user already exits"[, groups={"grp_name"}])
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="This email already exists"[, groups={"grp_name"}])
 */
class User
```

If you are using validation groups property in the form - then you have to specify it also in UniqueEntity constraint.

Comment: I tried this, but now nor email, nor username work.

 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Utilisateur",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="some_name", columns={"username", "email"})})

Comment: I'm reading your question again and I may be misunderstood it. Let's make it clear - do you want to have unique email and unique username (no same emails and no same usernames) or unique combination of name/email (so users can have same emails if usernames will be different)?

Comment: In my database I can have only one time each emails. And only one time each username.

Comment: It's the same as my first question, email will work fine, but username not.

Comment: I was not sure about using validation groups in your case. Exactly the same code is working in my testing environment now. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I added the form in question, I haven't validation group?

Comment: I have now tried with another attribute, name for example, and that work fine. This is with the username attribute that this not work, but I don't understand why...

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but you didn't answer - did you clear symfony cache?

Comment: I'm getting out of ideas... UniqueEntity validator is using repository method "findBy". Don't you have custom repository, where you modify findBy method? And another question - Symfony & Doctrine version?

Comment: In my security.yml file, I have this provider: http://puu.sh/mWKwu/ef28c87fc4.png

Maybe it is a problem? I don't have repository for this entity. I use symfony 2.7.8 and Doctrine 1.4